# BigQuery validator detects error but Query runs succesfully

Tags: google-bigquery

**UPDATE (3/25/21): [Bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/168097203) has been fixed and is no longer present**

I am trying to create a scheduled query that deletes a BigQuery ML model.

However the DDL statement suggested in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-drop-model) produces errors in the UI validator for no reason with a meaningless message :

```
DROP MODEL IF EXISTS `my_data.sample_model`
```

> training options cannot be empty

If you ignore it and still press run it gets the job done without a problem

> This statement deleted the model {project-name}:my_data.sample_model.

But you cannot turn it into a scheduled query because it simply cannot pass the validator ("Cannot schedule invalid queries") which creates a problem. What could be the reason for that error?

***EDIT***

Workarounds: Use either one of

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "DROP MODEL IF EXISTS `my_data.sample_model`"
```

as suggested by Yun Zhang

OR

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_data.sample_model`
```

[Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/168097203) filed in Google's issue tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug. Could you [create a bug on BigQuery here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

As a workaround for now, could you try scheduled query with dynamic SQL (to skip validation on the statement)

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "DROP MODEL IF EXISTS `my_data.sample_model`"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I find DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_data.sample_model` to work as well and pass the validator. I am not really sure if it has any disadvantages compared to the DROP MODEL statement.

Comment: DROP TABLE is not supposed to work. Try not to depend on it...